# Should I use autoregressive integrated moving average (ARIMA) models to forecast Market Size?

Tags: regression, time-series, forecasting, arima, marketing

I have historical sales data and used [ARIMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_integrated_moving_average) for volume forecast. For Market Size (Value), can I use ARIMA or any other technique where I can use forecastd volume as Input which I had from ARIMA output?

Answer (score 0):

That is called a [transfer function](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat510/lesson/9/9.1) might help.

Care should be taken to identify anomalies and to render them nul by incorporating empirically identied intervention variables.